Shared Preferences data retrieve not working - must refresh activity to get data
This code is working but you must refresh the Main activity to show the data saved in SharedPreferences. How can I display data in the first time without refreshing?
public class Profile {
    private String uid;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    public Profile() {
    }
    public Profile(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("user_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        // Retrieve the data from SharedPreferences
        this.uid = sharedPreferences.getString("uid", "N/A");
        this.firstName = sharedPreferences.getString("firstName", "N/A");
        this.lastName = sharedPreferences.getString("lastName", "N/A");
        this.email = sharedPreferences.getString("email", "N/A");
        this.phone = sharedPreferences.getString("phone", "N/A");
       }

// Method to saveuser data SharedPreferences

public void saveDataShared(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("user_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        // Put the data into SharedPreferences
        editor.putString("uid", this.uid);
        editor.putString("firstName", this.firstName);
        editor.putString("lastName", this.lastName);
        editor.putString("email", this.email);
        editor.putString("phone", this.phone);
editor.apply();
        }

// Method to clear user data from SharedPreferences
    public void clearDataShared(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("user_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        // Clear all data
        editor.clear();

        // Commit the changes
        editor.apply();
    }




 public void loadUserData(Context context) {
        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser currentUser = auth.getCurrentUser();

        if (currentUser != null) {
            String userId = currentUser.getUid();

            db.collection("users").whereEqualTo("uid", userId).get()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(queryDocumentSnapshots -> {
                        if (!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {
                            DocumentSnapshot dcprofile = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments().get(0);

                            this.setUid(dcprofile.getString("uid"));
                            this.setFirstName(dcprofile.getString("firstName"));
                            this.setLastName(dcprofile.getString("lastName"));
                            this.setEmail(dcprofile.getString("email"));
                            this.setPhone(dcprofile.getString("phone"));
                            
 // Save the loaded data to SharedPreferences
                            this.saveDataShared(context);
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(e -> Log.e("Profile", "Error loading user data", e));
        } else {
            // Handle the case where the user is not logged in
            Log.e("Profile", "User not logged in");
        }
    }

Login activity to save data in SharedPreferences by using Profile class and methods by Btn_login.setOnClickListener if login successful:
clearDataShared
loadUserData
saveDataShared 

        Btn_login = findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        Btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                hideKeyboard();
                String email,password;
                email=String.valueOf((editTextEmail.getText()));
                password=String.valueOf((editTextpaswword.getText()));


                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter email...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }

                auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
                                    Profile profile = new Profile();
                                    profile.clearDataShared(getApplicationContext());
                                    profile.loadUserData(getApplicationContext()); // Pass context
                                    profile.saveDataShared(getApplicationContext());

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);


                                }
                                else {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login failed! Please try again later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                }

                            }
                        });

            }
        });

Main activity to display data saved in SharedPreferences in "user_prefs":
public class MainActivity extends DrawerBaseActivity{
    ActivityMainBinding activityMainBinding;
    FirebaseAuth auth;
    FirebaseUser user;
    FirebaseFirestore db;

    Button Btn_Logout,Btn_add;

    TextView textView_info;
    private TextView datadText;
    private static final String TAG = "ProfileActivity";
    Profile myprofile;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        activityMainBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(activityMainBinding.getRoot());
        allocateActivityTitle("Main");
        datadText = findViewById(R.id.datadtext);

        auth =FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        user = auth.getCurrentUser();

        Btn_Logout =findViewById(R.id.btn_logout);

        textView_info =findViewById(R.id.text_info);



        if (user ==null){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }else {

            String infos = String.format("Email: %s\nUID: %s", user.getEmail(), user.getUid());
            textView_info.setText(infos);


            // Retrieve the data from SharedPreferences
            myprofile = new Profile(this);
            // Display the data
            datadText.setText(myprofile.toString());





        }

//    @Override
//    protected void onResume() {
//        super.onResume();
//
//        // Retrieve the data from SharedPreferences
//        myprofile = new Profile(this);
//        // Display the data
//        datadText.setText(myprofile.toString());
//    }

I tried onResume but it's not working
changing order in login Activity

You are not calling editor.apply() in your saveDataShared() method.
Your code:
public void saveDataShared(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("user_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    // Put the data into SharedPreferences
    editor.putString("uid", this.uid);
    editor.putString("firstName", this.firstName);
    editor.putString("lastName", this.lastName);
    editor.putString("email", this.email);
    editor.putString("phone", this.phone);
    }

Correct way:
public void saveDataShared(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("user_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    // Put the data into SharedPreferences
    editor.putString("uid", this.uid);
    editor.putString("firstName", this.firstName);
    editor.putString("lastName", this.lastName);
    editor.putString("email", this.email);
    editor.putString("phone", this.phone);
    editor.apply();
    }


editor.apply()
not working after add it
